# Search in IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I am pulling some data from database by this line below:

```
IQueryable<user> UserList = DatabaseContext.Users.GetAll();
```

I want to seach something in UserList such as:

```
foreach (var User in UserList)
{
    if (User.type == (int)UserType.SuperUser)
    {
        IsRecordFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then i do something according to the state of flag:

```
if (!IsRecordFound)
{
    AesCrypto aesCrypto = new AesCrypto();
    user newuser = new user();
    newuser.username = DEFAULT_SUPER_USER_NAME;
    newuser.password = aesCrypto.Encrypt(DEFAULT_SUPER_USER_PASSWORD);
    newuser.type = (int)UserType.SuperUser;
    newuser.create_date = DateTime.Now;
    newuser.last_login = newuser.create_date;
    newuser.email_address = DEFAULT_SUPER_USER_EMAIL_ADDR;
    newuser.login_count = 1;

    DatabaseContext.Users.Add(newuser);
    if (!DatabaseContext.Save())
        return false;
}
```

Is there any easy or practical way to seach in IQueryable interface by using LINQ or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!UserList.Any(x => x.Type == (int)UserType.SuperUser))
{
    AesCrypto aesCrypto = new AesCrypto();
    user newuser = new user();
    newuser.username = DEFAULT_SUPER_USER_NAME;
    newuser.password = aesCrypto.Encrypt(DEFAULT_SUPER_USER_PASSWORD);
    newuser.type = (int)UserType.SuperUser;
    newuser.create_date = DateTime.Now;
    newuser.last_login = newuser.create_date;
    newuser.email_address = DEFAULT_SUPER_USER_EMAIL_ADDR;
    newuser.login_count = 1;

    DatabaseContext.Users.Add(newuser);
    if (!DatabaseContext.Save())
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
bool isSuperUser =  UserList.Any(a=>a.type==a.SuperUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

to search an IQueryable, use `where`

```
var foundUsers = UserList.Where( usr => usr.Type == (int)UserTypes.SuperUser );

if( foundUsers == null && foundUsers.Count() == 0 ) // only one of these is required.. I forget which though :s
{
    AesCrypto aesCrypto = new AesCrypto();
    user newuser = new user();
    newuser.username = DEFAULT_SUPER_USER_NAME;
    newuser.password = aesCrypto.Encrypt(DEFAULT_SUPER_USER_PASSWORD);
    newuser.type = (int)UserType.SuperUser;
    newuser.create_date = DateTime.Now;
    newuser.last_login = newuser.create_date;
    newuser.email_address = DEFAULT_SUPER_USER_EMAIL_ADDR;
    newuser.login_count = 1;

    DatabaseContext.Users.Add(newuser);
    if (!DatabaseContext.Save())
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UserList .Where(user => user.Type== (int)UserType.SuperUser);
```